Motor rotating both clockwise and counter clockwise
I am building a drone, and I encountered an issue with one of the motors while testing it in Betaflight's Motors tab. When I move the slider, the motor behaves strangely. Up to the halfway point, it rotates counterclockwise, but beyond halfway, it slows down and starts rotating clockwise.
I have confirmed that the motor itself is not faulty. I also tried resetting the Betaflight settings, but the issue persists. I suspect the problem might be with the flight controller hardware or the ESC hardware,  I currently don't have spare components to verify this.
Additionally, I checked the PWM output duty cycle of the flight controller using a multimeter, and it remains constant regardless of the position of the motor slider in Betaflight.
Has anyone experienced a similar issue or knows what could be causing this? Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!
